# How can i consume this webservice with Java?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jboss

this is a very simple question apparently but i was unavaible to find a certain information searching in google. Let me tell you, i have a jboss running in my computer with only this webservice:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
@Path("/services/test")
public class TestController 
{
    @POST
    @Path("/reg")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response checkMock(String paramx)
    {
        return Response.ok("Paramx: " + paramx,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

}
```

Ok, to test it i use "Advance REST Client" chrome plugin and it is very simple, look this picture:

[image]

Well the question is, how can i do the same but with some java code in another program? What objecto do i require?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Spring RestTemplate](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate) to consume a Rest service.

You need to first register the `RestTesmplate` into spring context

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" id="restTemplate">
   <constructor-arg>               
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/> 
    </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

Once you registered your resttemplete in spring context you can  inject that in your service class and call the exchange method

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(payLoad, headers);

ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(ENDPOINT, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, ResponseObject.class);
ResponseObject resObj =  response.getBody();
```

Here `payLoad` is your request object and `ResponseObject`

To unmarshall the response directly into to response object you need to register the message converters

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ResponseObject.class);
MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(marshaller, marshaller);
marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
messageConverters.add(marshallingHttpMessageConverter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

Comment: Execellent Null, but one question, Should not be `ResponseEntity<Response>` instead of `ResponseEntity<String>` ? And in that case how can i access to the object `response` methods?

Comment: Where do you get "Jaxb2Marshaller" class? Eclipse does not suggest me any import.

Comment: You need to add  spring-oxm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar